# How to Downgrade the laravel, vuejs latest version to older versions like 5.5, 5.6, 2

Tags: laravel, vue.js

i wana degrade the laravel and vuejs version to older verions like 5.5, 5.6 and vue2. For laravel i have done some steps to convert lower version but it did't work,

Comment: fresh install laravel 5.6 by explicitly change in comoser.json

Comment: it does't work to explicitly change it there. After this the dependencies mismatch issues occurs. i solve my issue/error. and now i suggest https://laravel.com/docs/5.5, follow up laravel installation guid and there is installation guid for every version, it should work for all.